# Java Android How To Display Textview of Selected / Unselected Checkbox

Tags: android, checkbox, textview

Ok I know how to convert a checkbox into string and set it to a text on TextView but if I have 8 checkboxes, How can I have a textview that will dynamically change the string whenever I select or unselect other checkboxes.

Comment: Suppose if you have selected first checkbox then textview will display its value and so if you select some other checkbox should the previous value should be erased or not?

Comment: @nethragowda it should not be erased, it should add on. And if I uncheck any selected, the it should be erased but with those checked still there

Comment: your checkbox items are dynamic?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have done some work around hope this helps you

**activity_main.xml** file

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">


    <CheckBox
        android:id="@+id/checkBox1"
        android:layout_margin="10dp"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="item 1" />

    <CheckBox
        android:layout_margin="10dp"
        android:id="@+id/checkBox2"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="item 2" />

    <CheckBox
        android:layout_margin="10dp"
        android:id="@+id/checkBox3"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="item 3" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_margin="10dp"
        android:padding="15dp"
        android:id="@+id/action_text"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Hello World!" />
</LinearLayout>
```

And in the **MainActivity.java** file

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener {

CheckBox item1, item2, item3;
TextView textView;
ArrayList<String> StringArray = new ArrayList<>();

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    initViews();
}

public void initViews(){
    item1 = findViewById(R.id.checkBox1);
    item2 = findViewById(R.id.checkBox2);
    item3 = findViewById(R.id.checkBox3);
    textView = findViewById(R.id.action_text);

    item1.setOnCheckedChangeListener(this);
    item2.setOnCheckedChangeListener(this);
    item3.setOnCheckedChangeListener(this);
    setText();
}

@Override
public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
    if(isChecked) {
        StringArray.add("" + buttonView.getText().toString());
    } else {
        StringArray.remove(StringArray.indexOf(buttonView.getText().toString()));
    }
    setText();
}

public void setText(){
    textView.setText("");
    for (int i=0; i<StringArray.size();i++) {
        textView.append(StringArray.get(i));
        textView.append(",");
    }
}
}
```

Happy Coding ;)

Comment: Thank you so much !! This is exactly what I needed. Thanks alot !